# CSS - Select third DL

Tags: css, css-selectors

my markup is

```
<div class="gallery">
 <dl class="item">content 1</dl>
 <dl class="item">content 2</dl>
 <dl class="item">content 3</dl>

 <br style="clear: both">

 <dl class="item">content 4</dl>
 <dl class="item">content 5</dl>
 <dl class="item">content 6</dl>
</div>
```

now i want to select the third DL in the list. **content 3** and **content 6**, but this css selects only **content 3** but not **content 6**. the "br" between the "dl" makes something broken.

```
.gallery :nth-child(3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

any ideas?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use `dl:nth-of-type(3n)` instead to exclude the `br`:

```
.gallery dl:nth-of-type(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Alternatively, use another `:nth-child()` rule to apply clearance to the next `dl` after that, and get rid of that `br` because it's not needed:

```
.gallery dl:nth-child(3n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.gallery dl:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest using another technique? This does not need extra HTML mark-up. http://pathfindersoftware.com/2007/09/developers-note-2/

Comment: @BoltClock Confirm with the OP that they aren't using IE! `:P`

Comment: @Praveen Kumar: I don't need to do that when he has posted `:nth-child()` code that works even partially.

Comment: Maybe you could edit it to `.gallery dl:nth-child(3n+1)`? Just in case the gallery is larger than that. I also found out that `.gallery` doesn't take the height of its children. http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/r83RB/ But it does when using an `:after` http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/r83RB/

Comment: @Bram Vanroy: Ah, that's what you were referring to for using clearfix. I suppose it works there. That would have to depend on the layout... I edited my answer.